# Python split text and place into array

Tags: python, arrays, list, split

I dont really know how to explain it using english but:

```
inputText = "John Smith 5"
```

I want to split it and insert that to nameArray and make 5(string) into an integer.

```
nameArray = ["John", "Doe", 5]
```

And then place nameArray to fullNameArray

```
fullNameArray = [["John", "Doe", 5], ["John", "Smith", 5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use exception handling and `int()` here:

```
>>> def func(x):
...     try:
...         return int(x)
...     except ValueError:
...         return x
...     
>>> inputText = "John Smith 5"
>>> spl = [func(x) for x in inputText.split()]
>>> spl
['John', 'Smith', 5]
```

If you're sure it's always the last element that has to be converted then try this:

```
>>> inputText = "John Smith 5"
>>> spl = inputText.split()
>>> spl[-1] = int(spl[-1])
>>> spl
['John', 'Smith', 5]
```

use `nameArray.append` to append the new list to it:

```
>>> nameArray = []                              #initialize nameArray as an empty list  
>>> nameArray.append(["John", "Doe", 5])        #append the first name
>>> spl = [func(x) for x in inputText.split()]
>>> nameArray.append(spl)                       #append second entry
>>> nameArray
[['John', 'Doe', 5], ['John', 'Smith', 5]]
```

Comment: I used your second code but now my problem is I cannot populate the list as (spl =)... is there away to use append into spl aswell as splitting?

Comment: @BlupDitzz your `nameArray` must be a list of lists to get the desired output.

Comment: I get my desired output when I only input one name. When I input a second name, the second name is the one that is only printed

Comment: @BlupDitzz I've updated my code, try to do something like that.

Answer (score 2):

you are looking for `nameArray = inputText.split()`

The following code will work for any number in your string

so assuming the inputs are in a list called inputTextList:

```
fullNameArray = []
for inputText in inputTextList:
    nameArray = inputText.split()
    nameArray = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in nameArray]
    fullNameArray.append(nameArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> fullnameArray = [["John", "Doe", 5]] 
>>> inputText = "John Smith 5"
>>> fullnameArray.append([int(i) if i.isdigit() else i for i in inputText.split()])
>>> fullnameArray
[['John', 'Doe', 5], ['John', 'Smith', 5]]
```

The third line with the [conditional expression ("ternary operator")](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) inside a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (in case you're unfamiliar with that syntax) can also be written as:

```
nameArray = []
for i in inputText.split():
    if i.isdigit():
        nameArray.append(int(i))
    else:
        nameArray.append(i)
fullnameArray.append(sublist)
```